# Is this Possible update mysql table rows update automatically after some days.?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1064, myisam

I have a Problem with Mysql table... In this table more than 30,000 of rows. and at a time 3 process running and that is Select, Insert and Update on this table. the problem is that after Some days my two column named by status and delivery_date has been updated automatically..

Comment: Er...could you expand a bit on this, please? As it stands there is no question here.

Comment: so what's the problem?

Comment: "after Some days my two column named by status and delivery_date has been updated automatically" - if this is what you want, please add how it should be updated

Comment: @user1691954 Has your question been answered?

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a way how to schedule some SQL query/stored procedure for automatic execution, I can think of two options

1. Write a stored procedure that does what you need and use `CREATE EVENT` in MySQL ([documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html)). See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6560639/2032064).
2. If you enough rights on your PHP machine, then use `cron` to execute a (PHP) script that does what you want (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409891/using-cron-jobs-to-execute-php-script)). There are some alternatives for Windows too.