# how can mysql update its own data?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I got a mysql database which contains some trading orders(sell orders and buy orders). I want mysql to run my code written in javascript or php to 'trade' the orders. For example, if I have one sell order that sells 5 items at a certain price and one buy order that buys 3 items at the same price, I want the buy order to be filled and 2 items left for sell.

I can write code in html pages, so it trades every time when someone opens my url. However, I want it to keep trading on the server side no matter whether a users observes or not.

1. Can mysql calculates its own data automatically? How can I set up the trading process on mysql?
2. If 1 is not possible, can I write some javascript or php code and let mysql run my code automatically? How can I set it up?

Can anyone help please? Thanks!

Comment: A script has to be executed by the server. I would suggest you Google Cronjobs. It's scheduling mechanism that allows you to run a script without a user action. Thats the closest I can get to answering your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can have mechanism to make mysql to update its own data.

1. Using server side script and cron jobs, used mostly for scheduling some database job/scripts on server automatically or at intervals. 
    
    [Using Cron jobs to execute PHP script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409891/using-cron-jobs-to-execute-php-script)
   [how to run php file using cron jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097609/how-to-run-php-file-using-cron-jobs)
    
   http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/php-cron-job
2. Using 'Triggers' in mysql database, used mostly for calculation or job if there is a event of change on particular table or data.
   http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-triggers/

Answer (score 0):

`Can mysql calculates its own data automatically? How can I set up the trading process on mysql?`

No, you can't UNLESS there exists a script inside your server that would access the values inside MySQL. If you want an automated action for your server, CRON would be a start.

`If 1 is not possible, can I write some javascript or php code and let mysql run my code automatically? How can I set it up?`

You don't let MySQL run your PHP/JS code, rather you let JS/PHP get to MySQL. Make a PHP script (or whatever language you want), and let your browser run it, or use CRON to automatically execute it given on a specific time.